# Preventing borders in iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

I've tested *border: none*, *border: 0* and *overflow: hiden* as well as different variations of *seamless* parameter. The border of my iframe is gone but the scrolling thingies are still there.

In [this example](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/jobs/example-seamless/) I even get it to work on my computer fot **that** page. However, I can't get it to work for an arbitrary web page and I'm a little bit stuck.

What obvious thing am I missing?

In IE and Cr I get the scrolls. In FF, no scroll bars.

Comment: have you tried to hide the y axes only?

Comment: what browser(s) are you using?

Comment: Provide a sample in JSfiddle demonstrating your problem, now it's just a guessing game as is.

Comment: And the examples shows the source code. Right now, I deploy the third solution but that's not CSS, which would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to do it in CSS, would `scrolling=no` be ok for you?

`<iframe scrolling="no">`

Comment: Yes, for now. However, I prefer to do things the right way so I was hoping for something based on CSS only. Suggestions? (Setting *scrolling* attribute isn't HTML5 compliant, right?)